# How to get host name from php on shared hosting?

Tags: php, dns, shared-hosting

On shared hosting (on subdomain `notes.jcubic.pl`) I've try to use:

```
$host = gethostname();
```

but got `n114.domenomania.pl` (real server name) is there a way to get `notes.jcubic.pl` subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking lot the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?

Comment: Yes, that was it I just found it.

Comment: Mark as answered please

Comment: I needed to wait 10 minutes SO rule.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 5.3.0 use this:

$hostname = gethostname();

For PHP < 5.3.0 but >= 4.2.0 use this:

$hostname = php_uname('n');

For PHP < 4.2.0 use this:

$hostname = getenv('HOSTNAME'); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = trim(`hostname`); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = exec('echo $HOSTNAME');
if(!$hostname) $hostname = preg_replace('#^\w+\s+(\w+).*$#', '$1', exec('uname -a'));

Answer (score -1):

you can use this also for connecting in localhost server $db_host = "localhost";

Comment: I need host so I can send email with a link to my app, I can't use localhost.

Comment: I think you want an online host ? try free hosting like /www.000webhost.com/

Comment: I've already have a host but I've got real server name and not my domain.

Comment: did you try this ?   $host = gethostname(href="www.yourdomain");

Comment: I want to work with any domain not the one I have, it's open source project that should work anywhere. The domain can change. Also [gethostname don't accept optional parameters the args is void](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.gethostname.php) and also php don't have keyword arguments.